# Does kafka JDBC Sink Connector keeps track of data being loaded to destination database?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using kafka jdbc sink connector which insert data into SQL Server database from topic. Due to some issue in mssql connector is stopped with error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host mssql_ip , port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out.
```

My question is, will my current data be inserted to SQL Server once its started? Or it will start inserting data from that point of time?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst SQL Server is up and available, the Kafka Connect JDBC sink connector will send data to it.

If something breaks (network goes down, SQL Server stops, etc) then Kafka Connect will know where it got to in the topic (the *offset*) being sent, and will start from that point next time when you restart the connector.

If SQL Server is down, Kafka Connect cannot send data to it. Once SQL Server is started, you will need to restart your Kafka Connect connector task and it will then start sending data again.